# Inserting a subview and changing position of another view at the same method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to add a subview (`UITextField`) to a view and change the frame property of a `UITextView` in the same method but it's not working as I was expecting. This is the code:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 120, 240, 40);

[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
self.tvContent.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, self.tvContent.frame.size.width, self.tvContent.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.view insertSubview:textField aboveSubview:self.tvContent];
```

Note: tvContent is the `UITextView` object which I am trying to reposition.

The problem I am facing is that the `UITextView` isn't moving at all *IF* the last line of code (insertSubview) is in place. `The UITextField` does show up though. However, if I remove the last line , the textview change its position just fine.

I have also tried without animation by just setting the frame property of self.tvContent and same behavior occurred.

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 120, 240, 40);

[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
self.tvContent.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, self.tvContent.frame.size.width, self.tvContent.frame.size.height);
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinish)];
[UIView commitAnimations];

-(void)animationFinish {
[self.view insertSubview:textField aboveSubview:self.tvContent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are still using the good ol' `beginAnimations` thing?

This would do the same:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void) {
    self.tvContent.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, self.tvContent.frame.size.width, self.tvContent.frame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}];
```

EDIT: What happens if you just addSubView it?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the new animation method, thank you for the heads up. I tried your code and somehow the text view goes back to its original position after the animation ends. I have just tried commenting it out the insertSubview line and once again, the text view retained the position after the animation. Somehow the insertion of a subview is breaking up stuff. Any ideas why?

Comment: What happens if you just insert the subview with the "addSubview" method?